# How do I control the latch signal for the TLC5958 LED driver?

Tags: spi, led-driver, texas-instruments, led-matrix

I would like to drive 512 RGB LEDs with individually controllable brightness. My plan is to 8-way multiplex them so I would like to use an LED driver that is designed for multiplexing LED displays.

I was looking at the TLC5958 as it hits all my requirements: constant current sink PWM with lots of channels, supports multiplexing with a high refresh rate and relatively efficient data transfer (I would like to refresh the display at 120 Hz and display 30 frames per second of video data) and has functionality to reduce ghosting in multiplexed displays.

Looking at the datasheet and other supporting documents, it looks like controlling this LED driver is a bit different from most that I've seen. Data is sent into a shift register via a data in and clock line (so far so good), however the data is interpreted differently based on what command you send it. Commands are encoded on the number of clock rising edges that the latch signal remains high for before falling (for example, 1 rising edge means store the data from the shift register into the greyscale memory, 5 rising edges means store the data into the function control register, etc). And it appears to require this latch signal to be raised while data is being transferred and lowered when data transfer is complete. Therefore the latch signal must be synchronized with the data transfer clock.

I was hoping to just use an SPI channel on an external microcontroller or SoC to control the TLC5958, however I think the requirements on the latch signal preclude me from doing that easily. I think I can't just use a GPIO for the latch signal because it won't be synchronized with the SPI data clock.

Am I mistaken? What's the most straight forward way to control the TLC5958?

Comment: why dont you use addressable LEDs?

Comment: I didn't think addressable LEDs would suit my needs. I've arranged the LEDs into a 3D matrix and need them to be visible from all angles with minimum obstructions. Other than that I've already completed the construction with regular LEDs. The way it is constructed also requires multiplexing, as my plan was to multiplex to minimize the number of wires and connections.